# How to start the app that is associated to the IBackgroundTask I've created in UWP Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, win-universal-app, uwp

I implemented an IBackgroundTask on Universal Windows 10 and it works like a charm but the problem is that i want to start the app that is associated to that background task if some action occurs. The code is simple:

```
public sealed class AdvertisementWatcherTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    private IBackgroundTaskInstance backgroundTaskInstance;

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        backgroundTaskInstance = taskInstance;

        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTriggerDetails;

        if (details != null)
        {
            //Do things       
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen that you can create a ToastNotification like that:

```
Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlNodeList elements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
foreach (IXmlNode node in elements)
{
    node.InnerText = taskInstance.Task.Name+ " remember to uninstall task if not debugging";
}
ToastNotification notification = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(notification);
```

The notification toast works good. It creates and prompts a notification and if you click it, the app that created this background task starts. This is the behaviour that I want but I want to start the app without having to click any notification. Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you.

TL;DR: I want to start the app that created the background task at some point of the code.

Comment: I'm afraid there are no API's currently that can achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can not programmatically launch URI or open app from background task. You can however display a reminder or toast notification to let user open your app.